# Cannot see PC uploaded files on Google Drive with Android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to use the following code to list the root contents of my Google Drive account.

Unfortunately it only shows me **1 file** which is a file that was both created and deleted by my app. I have a number of files in the root folder which have been there for months so they should be visible (I am signing in with the same account on my app).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Get currently signed in account (or null)
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount( this );

// Synchronously check for necessary permissions
if( ! GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions( account, Drive.SCOPE_FILE ) )
{
  // Note: this launches a sign-in flow, however the code to detect the result of the sign-in flow and retry the API call is not shown here.
  GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions( this, RC_DRIVE_PERMS, account, Drive.SCOPE_FILE );
  return;
}

client = Drive.getDriveResourceClient( this, account );

// Start task - to get the root folder and contents..
rootFolderTask = client.getRootFolder();

Tasks.whenAll( rootFolderTask ).continueWithTask( new Continuation<Void, Task<MetadataBuffer> >()
{
  @Override
  public Task<MetadataBuffer> then( @NonNull Task<Void> task ) throws Exception
  {
    DriveFolder   parent       = rootFolderTask.getResult();

    listChildrenTask = client.listChildren( parent );

    return listChildrenTask;
  }
} )
.addOnSuccessListener( this,
        new OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer>()
        {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess( MetadataBuffer list )
          {
            Log.i( TAG, "Got child list Success(A)" );

            int nNumItems = list.getCount();

            Log.i( TAG, "Got " + nNumItems + " items" );

            for( int i = 0; i < nNumItems; i ++ )
            {
              Metadata md = list.get( i );

              Log.i( TAG, i + " getDriveId: " + md.getDriveId() );
              Log.i( TAG, i + " getTitle: " + md.getTitle() );
              Log.i( TAG, i + " isFolder: " + md.isFolder() );
              Log.i( TAG, i + " isTrashed: " + md.isTrashed() );
              Log.i( TAG, i + " getFileSize: " + md.getFileSize() );
              Log.i( TAG, i + " getFileExtension: " + md.getFileExtension() );
            }

            //showMessage( getString( R.string.file_created,
            //      driveFile.getDriveId().encodeToString() ) );
            //finish();
            list.release();
          }
        } )
```

My Logcat output:

```
01-05 14:27:24.150 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: Got child list Success(A)
01-05 14:27:24.150 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: Got 1 items
01-05 14:27:24.155 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: 0 getDriveId: DriveId:CAESITFwaGZ2TDhYM2UwWndpRXJ2elRwSG41Z3VWOFRqQW8zXxh-IPyMkcvdUigA
01-05 14:27:24.155 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: 0 getTitle: abhaytest2
01-05 14:27:24.155 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: 0 isFolder: false
01-05 14:27:24.155 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: 0 isTrashed: true
01-05 14:27:24.155 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: 0 getFileSize: 12
01-05 14:27:24.155 17248-17248/org.libsdl.app I/PDS: 0 getFileExtension:
```

I admit I'm not familiar with `Tasks`, `Continutation`s, `continueWithTask` and `addOnSuccessListener`.

Why am I not seeing the other files listed?

Is `addOnSuccessListener()` being called after all files have been retrieved, or is it only being called once on the first (ie. should I be using `continueWith` instead?)

**Update**: I get the same result if I use `continueWith` instead of `addOnSuccessListener`.

**Update**: Arghh! Google API documentation states the following for *querying* files:

*Note: The Android Drive API only works with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope. This means that only files which a user has opened or created with your application can be matched by a query.*

And..

*"A Scope that gives 'drive.file' access to a user's drive. This scope give per-file access to files that have been created by, or specifically opened with the app."*

It looks as though my application may not be allowed to open files which it did not create itself?? Surely this isn't true - this would stop me from having a Windows app and Android mobile app that can share files.

Maybe I should be using an 'app' folder?? (e.g. `getAppFolder()` )

However - I can't use the 'app' folder because Google states:

*"The app folder is a special folder within Drive that is only accessible by your application. Its contents are hidden from the user and from other apps. Although it is hidden from the user, the app folder does count against the user's Drive storage quota."*

There must be a way to create a shared folder that is visible to both an app and the user? Maybe Google Drive cannot (currently) be used to share file between Windows and an Android app - perhaps I need to use DropBox or something else?

**My Google Drive** has an **Open with->Connect more apps** menu option. That appears to let the user choose which app may view a folder/file.

How do you connect a development/debug app so that it can view contents of a folder when it hasn't been published in the Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions in your post, but short answer is you *can* see files that weren't created with the app. The catch is the user has to choose which file(s) to allow. You can use [newOpenFileActivityIntentSender](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveClient.html#newOpenFileActivityIntentSender(com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityOptions)) to do let users choose which files they authorize access to.

There's been a long standing feature request to allow authorization at the folder level, but so far that feature hasn't been implemented.

Of course you can always fall back on using the REST API with the full drive scope. The full scope is discouraged for security reasons -- apps rarely need to access **all** files a user has. You'd also give up some of the nicer features of the Android version of the API (e.g. offline support)

Comment: Thanks Steve. I implemented Dropbox in my app which does I want but prefer Google Drive. Don't really want to go down REST API route for the reasons you stated. If I could allow access to my app via the Google Drive web page, I would be happy with that - I guess that's the only question remaining - how can I authorise a developer debug app. I saw an old test app of mine in the "connected app" list - I just can't figure how to get my current test app to work the same. Must be a way?